# How to pass a variable from main to signal and slot macros?

Tags: c++, qt

Having the hardest time setting up signal and slot macros for variables in main.  It is extremely easy to do when the variables are located in classes, but how do you do this when you want to connect a variable in main?

I have two radio buttons in main as follows:

```
 QRadioButton *btn_ledWhite = new QRadioButton;
 QRadioButton *btn_ledBlack = new QRadioButton;
```

I want to pass these buttons to a function that sets their stylesheet.  Something like below:

```
 btn_led->setStyleSheet("QRadioButton::indicator::unchecked{background-color:gold;}");
```

When the user of my application presses `btn_start`, the white player's LED should light up.  Unfortunately, I cannot pass the buttons from main to signal and slot macros.    I want something like this:

```
 QObject::connect(btn_start, SIGNAL(clicked()), whiteClock, SLOT(updateLED(btn_ledWhite)));
```

This is illegal qt syntax, however.  Apparently, you cannot pass an argument to a function wrapped in a SLOT macro.

You can do something like:

```
Counter a, b;
QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                 &b, SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

... but I cannot mix the presentation (GUI) layer, with the business layer (i.e. standard 3-tier architecture model... think MVC).  Else I would just stick this button in a class and not worry make this thread.

Does anyone have idea how to connect a variable in main with a signal and slot macro?

Comment: I've tried to do something similar, but couldn't get it to work.  Very annoying syntax on Qt's part.  I believe you may have to emit a signal, then somehow catch it in a slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works.  You do need to adjust the function signature as previously mentioned to a QWidget*, instead of a QRadioButton*...but everything else should be the same.

**main.cpp**

```
QSignalMapper * signalMapper = new QSignalMapper;

//Start game, start white's clock, turn on white's LED
QObject::connect(btn_start, SIGNAL(clicked()), whiteClock, SLOT(startClock()));
QObject::connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget*)), whiteClock, SLOT(updateLED(QWidget*)));
QObject::connect(btn_start, SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
signalMapper->setMapping(btn_start, btn_ledWhite);
```

Set the stylesheet in your clock class and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`QSignalMapper`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html) for this.

You connect your buttons' `clicked()` signal to the mapper's `map()` slot, then set the mapping from button to led with the mapper's `setMapping` function.

Once that's done, connect the mapper's `mapped` signal to your `whiteClock`. You might need to adjust your slot function's signature to take a `QWidget` rather than a `QPushButton`, but if all you need is to call `setStyleSheet`, then that's not much of a problem.

Comment: Good answer. A `QObject` basically has its own signal mapper, but `main` does not.

Comment: @Mat Don't you mean the `mapped` signal, not slot?